# setting a jvm variable on CloudFoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have a Java application, using a jvm variable. Normally, I set it using a command like
`APP_HOME="-DAPP_HOME=$CATALINA_HOME/myapp"`
in order to point to the correct folder within my application structure on Tomcat. 
Now I am trying to deploy my application to the MicroCloud virtual machine. Once deployed, I use the command 
`vmc env-add myapp APP_HOME="-DAPP_HOME=$HOME/myapp`
to set my variable. But the problem is that the variable is set as a shell variable and not JVM variable. When I use `System.getenv();` I can see that my variable is set, but when I use `System.getProperty("APP_HOME")` the variable is null.
Anyone had experience with this and could recommend what to do set it as a JVM variable on CF?

p.s.
I read all the existing topics on the CloudFoundry Q&A and here on stackoverflow, but I do not see an answer to this problem...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

`vmc env-add myapp JAVA_OPTS="-DAPP_HOME=$HOME/myapp"`

(i.e. pass -DAPP_HOME as a property to the JVM)

However, why are you trying to do this - and why is it such a bad idea just to grab the value using getenv instead of looking for a system Property?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, that's exactly what I was looking for, but was too blind to see :) It works fine!
You are right, there is no particular reason why not to use getenv (env variables), besides the fact that the application was already developped to work with a jvm property and I don't want to change it all now only to be able to deploy it to CF...